# When upgrading django 1.4 to 1.6 users left unauthorized

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-1.4, django-1.6

On production host we have installed django 1.4 and wanted to upgrade it to latest release (1.6) After all needed changes are done we installed it and faced with the fact that all of our users were not authorized after restarting uwsgi processes.

Even that definition did not help:

`SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'`

So we had to rollback to django 1.4.9 while understand the reason of that behaviour.

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Are you using Django regular user or extending using AbstractUser?

Comment: If you storing data using pickle, have you checked to see if the definition of the data is the same for the pickle? Maybe it's expecting some "field" that is not present in 1.4. What is the traceback message that you get?

Comment: We are using now regular user. The main thing confused me is that on another host used for feature testing with same sources and database switching between django1.4 and 1.6 leaves user authenticated.

Comment: There is no traceback messages, just when opening page user is anonymous.